# Append query string parameters to form.action or a.href using Javascript?

Tags: xss, javascript, phishing, url

I have an HTML page which is accepting any number of query string parameters, which I need to pass on to the next page the user visits by clicking links on my page. Basically, if the user comes to

```
http://example.com/some/page.html?param1=123&param2=567&smthelse=abcde
```

Most of these query string parameters have tracking nature. I need to make sure that when the user clicks on certain links on this page or submits certain POST forms, all these query strings are passed along to the subsequent page.

If possible I am looking to avoid whitelisting/blacklisting query string parameters which should be allowed to be passed to the next page, as it is a lot of maintenance. Instead, I am planning to use jQuery/Javascript to dynamically read all query strings, and update anchors' href attributes and forms' action attributes to append the entire `window.location.search` value to these URLs.

Example ([jsbin](https://output.jsbin.com/tatagizimo?test1=1,test2=2)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pageQsParams = window.location.search.split('?')[1] || '';

    var newLinkUrl =   $('.link').attr('href') + (pageQsParams ? '?' + pageQsParams : '');
    $('.link').attr('href', newLinkUrl);

    var newFormUrl =   $('#form').attr('action') + (pageQsParams ? '?' + pageQsParams : '');
    $('#form').attr('action', newFormUrl);
});
```

is this code vulnerable to XSS or phishing? Any other security vulnerability? Any better way to do it?

Comment: as coded it's safe because it appends to a legit path in a non-templated way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is safe.

[`jQuery.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) isn't escapable via special characters, since it uses a [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) internally.

Since you set the href / action attributes, you must also check that the URL can't be manipulated by an attacker.

Since you prepend `?` to the query string, it will start the query string part in the final URL, and prevent any path/host manipulation, as long as the previous URLs were well-formed, and used a `http` or `https` scheme.

If the previous URLs used the `javascript` scheme, then a XSS vector would have been possible.